# jscrollpane mouse wheel not working in ie and ff

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

i am using jscrollpane i have apply scroll to div and i have one iframe inside div.

```
<div id="frameDiv">
<iframe id="frameID"  name="frameID" style="display:none;" width="220"  height="300" src="url" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">           </iframe>  
</div>
```

for the above code mouse wheel is not working in ie and ff.
its working fine in chrome and safari,

Answer (score 0):

To use jScrollPane with the mousewheel plugin successfully cross browser please see this example:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/iframe.html

I guess that you are currently using an approach like this:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/iframe2.html

Which as you will see in the notes has the drawback that the mousewheel doesn't work (due to security restrictions in the browsers).